# YUI 2.9 with new versions of browsers

Tags: browser, yui

We have developed a framework using YUI 2.9. As the newer versions of browser are released for  like a month eg FF. We have to do testing for all the component with newer version. Is there any way this testing can be compromised? YUI 2.9 will be compatible with new browsers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't develop new software with YUI 2. It isn't supported anymore by Yahoo! or the community. YUI 3 sometimes breaks with new browsers and it needs to be fixed, so there's a good chance of YUI 2 breaking.

Comment: Yeah, but it will take time for us to move to version 3. 
So what you are suggesting is we  should continue testing the whole component?

Comment: Testing on your own is always a good idea. My recommendation is to stop writing new code with YUI 2, just maintain what you already have. No new features should be written using YUI2. While you upgrade your codebase you can use YUI 2in3: http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/yui/yui-yui2.html